# Exception thrown even after correcting

Tags: vb.net, exception, try-catch

I am doing some validations in my page, and this validation is working fine. But when the user try to pass the correct value after the first failure try, this error is occurring `Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.`

**VB.NET:**

```
Protected Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
Try
  If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtHRRemarks.Text) Then
      If txtHRRemarks.Text.Trim().Length > 3 Then
      ModalPopUpExt.Hide()
      Throw New ApplicationException("Please reduce HR Remarks (max 500 chars)")
     End If
  End If
Catch ex As Exception
        Utilities.PageMessage = ""
        Utilities.DisplayExceptionDetails(ex)
End Try
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub Render(writer As HtmlTextWriter)
    If Utilities.PageError <> "" Then
        pnlMsgs.Visible = True
        Me.hfErrMsg.Value = "Error"
        Dim Validator As New RequiredFieldValidator
        Validator.ErrorMessage = Utilities.PageError
        Validator.ValidationGroup = "ErrorGroup"
        Validator.IsValid = False
        Validator.Visible = False
        placeholderError.Controls.Add(Validator)
        Utilities.PageError = ""
        upErrorMsg.Update()

    ElseIf Utilities.PageMessage <> "" Then
        pnlSccs.Visible = True
        lblSuccess.Text = Utilities.PageMessage
        Utilities.PageMessage = ""
        upSuccessMsg.Update()
        Utilities.PageMessage = ""
    Else
        pnlMsgs.Visible = False
    End If
    MyBase.Render(writer)
End Sub
```

The error is occurring after the user correct the data caught by the validation.

Comment: Do you mean the error you `Throw`?

Comment: @OneFineDay when the exception thrown and the user correct the value and put it less than 3, it occurs the error mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the code...

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtHRRemarks.Text) Then
  If txtHRRemarks.Text.Trim().Length > 3 Then
  ModalPopUpExt.Hide()
  Throw New ApplicationException("Please reduce HR Remarks (max 500 chars)")
 End If
End If
```

So if txtHRRemarks.Text.Trim().Length > 3 you are **always** throwing an exception!

Comment: Yes, I did this for testing.

Comment: The problem is when the exception thrown and the user correct the value and put it less than 3, it occurs the error mentioned in the question.